# How to implement fixed header for table in css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Can anybody tell How to implement fixed header for table in css.In our application have table with vertical scrollable. Can anybody tell how to avoid scroll for header and body content need to scroll without using jQuery

Thanks

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: [Plenty to choose from](https://www.google.com/search?q=fixed+table+header+pure+css&oq=fixed+table+header+pure+css)

Answer (score 0):

Use position fixed or sticky for the header.

In case you want to learn more about css positioning the article is very useful.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/